# Intellij IDEA: Compare Files: How To Change Sides?

Tags: intellij-idea

I use Intellij IDEA for comparing two files in the side by side view.

How can I change the sides, so that the file visible on the left side appears on the right side and vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround is to select which file goes on which side when you start the comparison.

1. Open the right-hand file in the editor window.
2. Select the left-hand file from the list (e.g. under "Project Files").
3. Right-click on the left-hand file and select "Compare File with Editor".

Answer (score 6):

There is an open feature request, feel free to vote:

- [IDEA-48213](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-48213) Compare two files action does not allow to select which file will be left and which one will be right (swap diff)

Answer (score 2):

When comparing 2 local files there is a swap files button...  For VCS comparison this button is missing...